# How to simulate mouse down/up/drag inside NSView

Tags: ios, macos, mouse, move

I'm looking for a solution how to simulate mouse down/up/drag events in OSX applications.

Right now I'm using this code:

```
switch (packetType) {
    case QCPacketTouchStarted:
        evtType = NSLeftMouseDown;
        mouseEvent = [NSEvent mouseEventWithType:evtType
                                        location:point
                                   modifierFlags:nil
                                       timestamp:[NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]
                                    windowNumber:self.myView.window.windowNumber
                                         context:[NSGraphicsContext currentContext]
                                     eventNumber:nil
                                      clickCount:1
                                        pressure:1];
        [self.myView mouseDown:mouseEvent];
        break;

    case QCPacketTouchMoved: {
        evtType = NSLeftMouseDragged;
        mouseEvent = [NSEvent mouseEventWithType:evtType
                                        location:point
                                   modifierFlags:nil
                                       timestamp:[NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]
                                    windowNumber:self.myView.window.windowNumber
                                         context:[NSGraphicsContext currentContext]
                                     eventNumber:nil
                                      clickCount:1
                                        pressure:1];
        [self.myView mouseDragged:mouseEvent];
    }
        break;

    case QCPacketTouchEnded:
        evtType = NSLeftMouseUp;
        mouseEvent = [NSEvent mouseEventWithType:evtType
                                        location:point
                                   modifierFlags:nil
                                       timestamp:[NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]
                                    windowNumber:self.myView.window.windowNumber
                                         context:[NSGraphicsContext currentContext]
                                     eventNumber:nil
                                      clickCount:1
                                        pressure:1];
        [self.myView mouseUp:mouseEvent];
        break;

}
```

The problem is that mouseDown and mouseUp events are handled correctly (view is recieving clicks), but mouse isn't moving on mouseDragged events. What I'm doing wrong here?